# Create video of arbituary length

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, shell

I'm trying to create a video file, either `.mp4` or `.mov`, that has a specific length, for example 59 hours. It doesn't matter what's inside the video, it can be just blank. I found this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895709/6282576):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4
```

Which takes an images and creates a fixed-length video from that image. It works, but it takes a long time to do that. Are there any other ways one can create blank videos of fixed length that doesn't take long to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have specific requirements in terms of video codec settings, you can generate the video based on one black frame ([see `color`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) source):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:duration=60:size=320x240:r=1 -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

We're using one frame per second (`r=1`), but you can go even lower (e.g. `r=0.01`) to encode only one frame for 60 seconds, and nothing else.

Another method suggested by Gyan should be much faster:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:size=320x240 -vf trim=end_frame=2,setpts=N*59*3600/TB -c:v libx264 -vsync 0 -video_track_timescale 100 out.mp4
```

Here:

- `trim=end_frame=2` removes everything but the first two frames
- `setpts=N*59*3600/TB` sets the timestamp of the first frame to 0, and the second one to 59 hours (59 × 3600 seconds), divided by a constant (TB)
- `-vsync 0` makes ffmpeg use these timestamps as-is without forcing a specific framerate (otherwise you'd get duplicated frames)
- `-video_track_timescale` sets the time base (TB) to 100, which is required since otherwise the generated PTS numbers would be too large

Comment: Suggest `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:size=320x240 -vf trim=end_frame=2,setpts=N*59*3600/TB -c:v libx264 -vsync 0 -video_track_timescale 100 out.mp4`

Comment: Good suggestion, I added it and explained what it means.

Comment: I prefer the vsync strings over numbers as it is less cryptic: `-vsync passthrough`. Using `r` in color instead of `-r` would be faster as it would avoid 25 to 1 conversion.